# HTTPResponse - Return organised data (table?)

Tags: python, django

My Webservice is currently returning a HTTPResponse which contains thousands of data from a mySQL database (via a Objects.filter). It's currently just displating them in a very boring way!

I'm looking to organised this data in some way. What would be ideal is two things:

The possibility of having a table and maybe having some kind of scroll bar?

Does anyone have any idea what I'm referring to or what package would help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to return pure HTML (as opposed to, say, JSON and Javascript to show it)? If so, the `<table>` [tag](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp) of HTML seems to be what you want; and [this](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/help/ftopic2394.html) is a way to have a scrollbar on the table.

Comment: Is it possible to wrap Ajax code/general divs around the HttpResponse?

Comment: Sure, you can put anything you want in your template (or even inject it from the view though in general that's less advisable).